# Code formatting in eclipse in exception scenario

Tags: eclipse, formatting

=== Before formatting ===

```
@ApiResponses(
            value = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            description = "Found details",
                            content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Bean.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "422", description = "Validation error", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad request", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }) })
    public ResponseEntity userDetails() {
    
    }
```

=== After formatting ===

```
@ApiResponses(
            value = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Found details", 
                    content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation =Bean.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "422", description = "Validation error", 
                    content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad request", 
                    content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal server error", 
                    content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorBn.class)) }) })
    public ResponseEntity userDetails() {
    
    }
```

=== Before formatting ===

```
@HystrixCommand(
            fallbackMethod = "createUserPreferenceFallBack",
            commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "30000"),
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE") })
```

=== After formatting ===

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "createUserPreferenceFallBack", commandProperties = { 
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "3000"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "SEMAPHORE") })
```

How to do that?

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: java language in sts editor

Comment: Java? Your question doesn't say this. I don't know what you mean by _sts editor_ and I can't see common rules for formatting here (different indents for `value` and `content`; annotation and annotated metode differently indented; etc.).